# Ionic 3 - All imports are unused warning (even though they are being used)

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic3

I am getting the following error when trying to run a prod build using the following

> ionic cordova build browser --prod

Getting  lot of warnings in the terminal like

> FormBuilder is declared but never used

Even though in my code I am importing it and using it e.g.

```
import { Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

public form: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {

setForm(){
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      password2: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Has anyone had a similar problem? My guess it would be something to do with an npm package update.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that you should delete your `node_modules` folder after updating the project to Ionic3, then run `npm install` again. With the new CLI these warnings will be more aggressive, prepare yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have deleted them and re-installed many times now. Updated to Ionic 3 a while back and didn't have this issue, only starting occurring recently.

Comment: I have the same issue, any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ionic 3.3.0 (2017-05-24) removed the usage of legacy file 'src/declarations.d.ts' as mentioned in the [changelog](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#330-2017-05-24). Removing 'declarations.d.ts' from the src/ folder fixes the unused imports warning.

For more info check out the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1052#issuecomment-327408336).

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and this is because tslint 5.0 changed how it checks unused variables.

You can suppress the warnings by changing the rules of the **tslint.json** file. I changed the "no-unused-variable" from true to false so it will look something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-unused-variable": [
      false
    ]
  },
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/tslint-eslint-rules/dist/rules"
  ]
}
```

Of course this will suppress all warnings about unused variables but at anytime you can revert it to true to see if there are any other unused variables.

You can also add the following variable **"noUnusedLocals": true** to the **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
.
.
.
}
```

Just know that the **"noUnusedLocals": true** will throw errors instead of warnings though...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Working form with my ionic 3 App:

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators  } from '@angular/forms';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-mobile-login',
  templateUrl: 'mobile-login.html',
})
export class MobileLoginPage {
    public loginForm:FormGroup;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
      public navParams: NavParams,
      public formBuilder: FormBuilder) 
      {
          this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
              mobile: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[0-9 ]*'),
                Validators.maxLength(10),Validators.minLength(10)])]
            });
      }


}
```

Seems issue you are using another function `setForm()` in constructor.

> mobile-login.html

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="submitMobile()" novalidate>
  <ion-list padding-right padding-left>
    <ion-item no-padding>
      <ion-input formControlName="mobile" type="tel" 
        placeholder="Enter Mobile" minlength="10" maxlength="10"
        [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.mobile.valid && loginForm.controls.mobile.dirty">
      </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item no-padding class="error-message" 
      *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.mobile.valid && loginForm.controls.mobile.dirty">
      <p ion-text>
        Enter Valid Mobile Number
      </p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

    <ion-row responsive-sm padding-right padding-left>
      <ion-col class="otpbutton">
        <button color='navbarColor' class="bluebg" ion-button block icon-left type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
        <ion-icon name="phone-portrait"></ion-icon>
            Submit
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </form>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? I don't think that the solution is just turn off the flag on unused variables. 
I have the same declarations of this answer, but still with the same warning. :/